# Currently Connected Receiver

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I'm developing an Android app which supports Chromecast and to do that I'm using a combination of MinimalCastMediaRouteProvider + a custom receiver. All is well with the playback but the Chomecast UX guide has a section headed [Cast menu functions appropriately for available receiver devices](https://developers.google.com/cast/design_consider#sender-cast-menu-available). It seems to state that when the Chromecast device is already connected to a service it should have a label indicating it, like the following with netflix:

[image: netflix image]

The issue is that on my device all I see is this:

[image]

where it's missing the "casting xxx" while I have another device casting to it. Is there something I need to set in my receiver app or is it something in the Android code? I don't see any documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything on your side at this point; there is currently a bug in the preview sdk that doesn't let that to work properly.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will it work in the future automatically or will it need to be defined explicitly?